# What is the best way to access an element from 2d array saved as a hash value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash, its values are 2 dimensional arrays, e.g.

```
hash = {
"first" => [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
"second" => [[7,88,9],[6,2,6]]     
}
```

I want to access the elements to print them in xls file.

I did it in this way:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |arr1|
    arr1.each do |arr2|
      arr2.each do |arr3|
        sheet1.row(row).push arr3
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to access each single element without using each-statement 4 times?

The desired result is to get each value from key-value pair as an array, e.g.

```
=> [1,2,3,4,5,6] #first loop
=> [7,88,9,6,2,6] #second loop
 #and so on
```

Comment: `value` refers to the outer array (I'd call it `values`), `arr1` is an inner array, e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`, `arr2` is an integer (misleading variable name, isn't it?) and `arr2.each` results in a `NoMethodError`, because there's no `Integer#each`. So yes, there probably is a better way – one without error ;-)

Comment: Please edit show your desired result for your example.

Comment: `hash.transform_values(&:flatten).each_value {|v| #code here }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as something like:

```
hash.each do |k,v|
  sheet1.row(row).concat v.flatten
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = { "first" =>[[1, 2,3],[4,5,6]],
         "second"=>[[7,88,9],[6,2,6]] }

hash.values.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 88, 9, 6, 2, 6]]
```

Comment: Please let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: No, I don't mean printing the whole hash, but printing the values of each each pair. In the above example I want to print all values from "first" (also [1,2,3,4,5,6]) then in the next loop I get the values of "second" and so on. So that I loop just one time over all keys and each time I get the values of the corresponding key.

Comment: The OP's comment referred to an earlier version of my answer.